# Foreign Key not recognizing Parent Key

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to insert values into my table but it's saying that parent key is not found even though it is populated.  Specifically, the foreign Key that points to the savings_acc primary key which is account_num.  I'm not sure if the problem is account_num is the primary key in two separate tables.

```
CREATE TABLE HAS_ACC
(
customer_num        char(10)          NOT NULL,
account_type        char(10)             NOT NULL,
account_num         char(10)             NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT has_acc_pk
PRIMARY KEY (customer_num,account_type,account_num),

CONSTRAINT customers_fk
FOREIGN KEY (customer_num) REFERENCES customers(customer_num),

CONSTRAINT accounts1_fk
FOREIGN KEY (account_num) REFERENCES CHECKING_ACC(account_num),

CONSTRAINT accounts2_fk
FOREIGN KEY (account_num) REFERENCES SAVINGS_ACC(account_num)

);
```

Acccount_num
S1234       B1234   21-AUG-19   100 0.05
S1235       B1235   21-AUG-19   100 0.05
S1236       B1236   21-AUG-19   100 0.05
S1237       B1237   21-AUG-19   100 0.05
S1238       B1238   21-AUG-19   100 0.05

Error:

INSERT INTO HAS_ACC VALUES (customer_num(i),account_type(i),account_num(i));
END;
Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MLONERGA.ACCOUNTS2_FK) violated - parent key not found
ORA-06512: at line 45
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
*Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
*Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.

Comment: Are the datatypes the same in both tables? `char` should probably be the standard string type `varchar2` to avoid problems with blank padding semantics.

Comment: Yes, everything is set the same: char(10).

Comment: Please explain the text following "Acccount_num ...". And you're inserting values from a collection so also show its definition.

Comment: account_num is the primary key in the CHECKING_ACC table and the SAVINGS_ACC table.  It is is a FORIEGN KEY in the HAS_ACC table and also part of the composite primary key in HAS_ACC

Comment: Sample data that reproduces the issue would really help here. I’ve never seen a case where a FK constraint wrongly reported that a value was not present in the parent table.